# Change location of .zip c#

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
    namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string appdata = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            string subFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appdata, ".minecraft");
            string bin = System.IO.Path.Combine(subFolderPath, "bin");
            string mods = System.IO.Path.Combine(subFolderPath, "mods");
            string coremods =System.IO.Path.Combine(subFolderPath, "coremods");
            string config = System.IO.Path.Combine(subFolderPath, "config");
            if (Directory.Exists(mods)) Directory.Delete(mods,true);
            if (Directory.Exists(config)) Directory.Delete(config, true);
            if (Directory.Exists(coremods)) Directory.Delete(coremods, true);




            FastZip fZip1 = new FastZip();
            fZip1.ExtractZip(@"C:\Users\Rafa\Desktop\MagicFarm.zip", subFolderPath, "config");


            FastZip fZip = new FastZip();
            fZip.ExtractZip(@"C:\Users\Rafa\Desktop\MagicFarm.zip", subFolderPath, "mods");

            FastZip fZip2 = new FastZip();
            fZip2.ExtractZip(@"C:\Users\Rafa\Desktop\MagicFarm.zip", subFolderPath, "coremods");
```

I want to put the "C:\Users\Rafa\Desktop\MagicFarm.zip" in the directory of the project.

Can someone help me?

Comment: When you say "the directory of the project" what do you mean? do you want the program to check the same folder the program was run from to look for the zip? Or do you mean you want the zip distributed with the exe so running your exe extracts the zip?

Comment: Remember that once your program is compiled, it has no idea where your original source code files are saved. The only place it will be able to save the ZIP file is in the same folder that the EXE is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `File.Move`. This also shows you how to get the current directory that the program is in.

```
//your zip
string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\Rafa\Desktop\MagicFarm.zip";
//the current directory that your exe is running from + the name
string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MagicFarm.zip")

// To move a file or folder to a new location:
System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```

Comment: You should use Path.Combine vs. "path" + "file"

Comment: You are close, but I don't think he wants to move from the desktop to the folder the program is running, he wants to look for the zip in the same folder the program was run from without hardcoding in the path to the desktop. Your `destinationFile` variable is all he really is looking for. Take a second and look what is program is doing, it is unzipping a zip file to the Minecraft install directory, he is just looking for a way to have the program moved to a different computer and still unzip.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look on [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.move.aspx), this could help ;)